# Como parar um serviço?

Tags: java, android, android-service

Eu criei uma conexão VPN no meu app através de um serviço, ao clicar de um botão, a conexão é feita. Mas agora quero saber como fazer o inverso, ou seja, ao clicar no botão desativar essa conexão. Como posso fazer isso?

Procedimento para chamar a conexão:

```
public void vpn() {
    Intent intent = android.net.VpnService.prepare(getApplicationContext());

    if (intent != null) {
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    } else {
        onActivityResult(0, RESULT_OK, null);
    }
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DNSVpnService.class);
        startService(intent);
    }
}
```

Classe DNSVpnService:

```
public class DNSVpnService extends android.net.VpnService {

    private Thread mThread;
    private ParcelFileDescriptor mInterface;
    //a. Configure a builder for the interface.
    Builder builder = new Builder();

    // Services interface
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // Start a new session by creating a new thread.
        mThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    //a. Configure the TUN and get the interface.
                    mInterface = builder.setSession("OpenDNS")
                            .addAddress("192.168.0.1", 24)
                            .addDnsServer("208.67.222.222")
                            //.addRoute("0.0.0.0", 0)
                            .establish();
                    //b. Packets to be sent are queued in this input stream.
                    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(
                            mInterface.getFileDescriptor());
                    //b. Packets received need to be written to this output stream.
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(
                            mInterface.getFileDescriptor());
                    //c. The UDP channel can be used to pass/get ip package to/from server
                    DatagramChannel tunnel = DatagramChannel.open();
                    // Connect to the server, localhost is used for demonstration only.
                    tunnel.connect(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 8087));
                    //d. Protect this socket, so package send by it will not be feedback to the vpn service.
                    protect(tunnel.socket());
                    //e. Use a loop to pass packets.
                    while (true) {
                        //get packet with in
                        //put packet to tunnel
                        //get packet form tunnel
                        //return packet with out
                        //sleep is a must
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Catch any exception
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        if (mInterface != null) {
                            mInterface.close();
                            mInterface = null;
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }
                }
            }

        }, "OpenDNS");

        //start the service
        mThread.start();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (mThread != null) {
            mThread.interrupt();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Para parar o serviço chame o método stopService() passando-lhe um Intent igual ao que usou para o iniciar

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DNSVpnService.class);
stopService(intent);
```

Comment: Eu já fiz isso, o comando é executado mas a VPN continua ativa...

Comment: Você perguntou como se pára um serviço, ele pára-se assim. Em relação à VPN, provavelmente terá de fazer algo no `onDestroy()` do serviço.